# Generator/Seed for AngularJS Directive Library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

There are multiple projects to easily bootstrap Angular application, e.g angular-seed, Yeoman angular generator.

Is there anything similar for AngularJS Directive Library? (library of reusable components to be used in multiple applications).

Requirements:

- each directive has HTML template
- each directive has JavaScript code
- each directive has CSS (or LESS)
- Gruntfile
- Karma configuration
- development server (livereload, etc.)

AngularUI Bootstrap (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) is good example of such project (it does not use CSS though).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something close to your requirements, Angular UI Publisher. Helper component for building and publishing your own angular modules/directives as bower components.

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-publisher

Addition of things like livereload, to Grunt tasks, are relatively easy.

Comment: Not exactly a seed/template/generator, but thanks for the link.